# How can create a test in laravel for check load relationships

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit, relationship, eager-loading

```
 public function test_show_role_should_return_actions()
    {
        $this->actingAs($this->user, 'api');
        $this->withHeaders(['Accept' => 'application/json',])
            ->get(route('roles.show', ['role' => $this->role->id]))
            ->assertJsonStructure([
                "data" => [
                    "name",
                    "actions" => [
                        "name",
                        "code"
                    ]
                ]
            ]);
    }
```

when I run the test,I have this error:

1. Tests\Feature\Role\RoleTest::test_show_role_should_return_actions
   Failed asserting that an array has the key 'name'.
   Even when I remove the "name",I get an error for the "actions" key.

[image: This is data that I get form Postman]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 public function test_show_role_should_return_actions()
    {
        $this->actingAs($this->user, 'api');
        $this->getJson(route('roles.show', ['role' => $this->role->id]))
            ->assertJsonStructure([
            'data' => [
                '*' => [
                    'name',
                    'actions' => [
                        '*' => [
                            'name',
                            'code'
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: Quick recommendation, don't do `->withHeaders(['Accept' => 'application/json',])`, but instead use `->getJson` and that will automatically ask for Json. Have a look at the [official docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/http-tests#testing-json-apis) about that

Comment: @matiaslauriti Thanks, I changed my code.